# Object manager in magento2

Tags: object-manager

What is object manager in magento2? Is it good to avoid use of it in Magento and where shall we make use of object manager ?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

Comment: You can use the ObjectManager on UniteTest and IntegrationTest